# Monitoring tools for IoT systems

Tags: software, monitoring

I'm looking for a software tool for the monitoring of the IoT system in my building. Data inputs are accessible via MQTT or API requests (alternatively, directly accessing a InfluxDB time-series database is an option).

It is a fully electric building and typical devices would be electric vehicles and their chargers, solar panels, electric hot water tanks, air conditioners and so on ... So there should be a way to show temperatures, filling level indicators, heat and power flow etc., maybe Sankey diagrams and so on. Diagrams displaying information and signal flow should also be possible, in order to be able to show control system functionalities. Other criteria would include simplicity  ... the tool is not just to be used by me, but by university students, who should get the hang of it quickly without spending weeks of reading documentation. Furthermore, the tool should ideally be free of charge, or at least have a limited cost of fewer than 100 euros per month.

There seem to be many tools available, but most of them require a lot of work before a clear picture has formed about the capabilities, pros and cons ...

Some assistance, some insight, possible candidates would be very helpful. So far, I have identified 13 IoT platforms or dashboard tools and I put them together in a table and put in the minimum reasonable cost, the available input interface protocols I was able to identify, if they have a sankey diagram available and a subjective impression I got regarding their ease of use, their capabilities and the quality of their visualisation features (impression I got after briefly looking at pictures or videos).

If anyone ever worked with one of these tools, some insight if they would make sense for my application would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak to AWS' IoT platform. It is certainly reliable and provides a lot of functionality. However there is a significant learning curve, especially if the user has never worked with AWS before.

Based on the criteria in your post, I would recommend you also have a look at [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). It is a great monitoring tool that is easy to learn, can be self-hosted for free, and supports customization. It can also be set up to work with AWS' IoT platform should your needs expand.